# Optimized process of moving records in the range of 1 million to 10 million

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What would you do if you had to massage data and move it from a database on one server to a database on another server?
Massage data was limited to using CONVERT or CAST. This process was called by a Data Loader in C#.NET. The SQL scripts were executed in SQL Server 2008.
Would you suggest this process be done using SQLBulkCopy, LINQ to SQL or should this be only done using a INSERT........ SELECT in TSQL?
The data could consist in the range of 1 million to 10 million rows.
I would appreciate your views on this process to verify an opitimized process on performing the above operation.

Comment: Do you have an access to both databases configuration?

Comment: Yes I have access to both database configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL should be avoided here; it isn't optimised for this (it is aimed at individual objects/records - not bulk). A cross-db (and possibly linked-server) insert/select is possible, but I would be looking at bulk options. I suspect SSIS (ex DTS) might be of use here - it is pretty much *designed* for this. If you need a managed option, a data-reader from the source (ExecuteDataReader()) connected to SqlBulkCopy to the target will perform the same function as SSIS (using the same bulk protocol).

Comment: I would think that performance is better when you are doing an insert... select... between database-tables on the same server using T-SQL. But across servers SqlBulkCopy (using ADO.NET when using server side code) seems a better option keeping in mind the large dataset. I agree with you that LINQ-to-SQL should be avoided here. SSIS using Bulk copy is definitely another option if you want to kick it off as a job rather than from c# code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on amount of data you're going to operate I would personaly choose ReplicationServices http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx and avoid programming solution , if it's possible.

Comment: To me the question suggests a simple copy - not a synchronised replicated setup

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues like these before. I solve this issue by SQLBulkCopy. bcp is great in performance.

Comment: I am not exporting the data from a file into the process so I do'nt think BCP would serve its purpose here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx    SqlBulkCopy definitely looks a better option. thanks in advance.